# How to eliminate the \\ at the end of a longtable

Tags: tables, longtable

I define a macro `\mycmd` like this

```
\newcommand\mycmd[2]{{some complicated format #1}&{some complicated format #2}\\}
```

to simplify the input. So I can just write:

```
sometext

\begin{longtable}{cc}
  \mycmd{contentA1}{contentA2}
  \mycmd{contentB1}{contentB2}
  \mycmd{contentC1}{contentC2}
  ...
```

But, at the end of the longtable, as

```
  \mycmd{contentZ1}{contentZ2}
\end{longtable}

some text
```

there is a white space between longtable and text. How can I eliminate the space by just setting a command at the end of the last `\mycmd` like

```
  \mycmd{contentZ1}{contentZ2}\avalidmacro
\end{longtable}

some text
```

to let the table near to the text?

---Resupply MWE for comparison---

```
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
\begin{longtable}{cc}
  sample table text&sample table text\\
\end{longtable}

main text main text main text main text

\begin{longtable}{cc}
  sample table text&sample table text
\end{longtable}

main text main text main text main text

main text main text main text main text
```

---Edit for Yiannis---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,xcolor}
\def\fqdi{fqd}
\def\fqdv{\fqdi\ \fqdi\ \fqdi\ \fqdi\ \fqdi\ }

\begin{document}
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
\itshape 
\fqdv\fqdv

\begin{longtable}{cc}
\color{red}\fqdv\fqdv&\color{red}\fqdv\fqdv\\
\end{longtable}

\fqdv\fqdv

\begin{longtable}{cc}
\color{red}\fqdv\fqdv&\color{red}\fqdv\fqdv
\end{longtable}

\fqdv\fqdv

\fqdv\fqdv

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\color{blue}\fqdv\fqdv&\color{blue}\fqdv\fqdv
\end{tabular}

\fqdv\fqdv
\end{document}
```

The red is the text in longtable, the blue is the text in tabular, black the main text.

- You will find a **slightly** space added to the first line's red and the second line's black.
- The red is not centered between lines, while the blue is.

Queation:

1. eliminate the effect of `\\`;
2. make `longtable`'s text same as `tabular`'s text, centering between lines.

Comment: `\setlength{\LTpost}{-15pt}` or to suit

Comment: @Caramdir Edited.

Comment: @Yiannis Edited.

Answer (score 4):

It is not your command, but rather the amount of glue allowed at the end of the table. See this minimal and adjust slightly the `LTpost` value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,longtable}
\newcommand\addrow[2]{{some complicated format #1}&{some complicated format #2}\\}
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}\setlength{\LTpost}{-1pt}%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{longtable}{cc}
%\hline
  \addrow{contentA1}{contentA2}
  \addrow{contentB1}{contentB2}
  \addrow{contentC1}{contentC2}
  \addrow{contentZ1}{contentZ2}
%\hline
\end{longtable}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

It is always better to fully provide a working minimal, as I have done here. Uncomment the `\hline` to see the space between the rows. Also it is better to use "semantic" commands, for example instead of `\mycmd` rather use `\addrow`.

Comment: I have edited the origin post. Could you read it again? I wish there is a clever way instead of just directly decrease the `\LTpost`.

Answer (score 3):

longtable wasn't really expecting to have to stitch tightly into the vertical list like this normally it's offset by some space or starts a new page. It could try harder, but currently you can correct for the depth of the previous paragraph (like most tabular `longtable` uses struts so its height and depth are known in reasonable cases.

I extended the test file with some digits at the start of the lines to make it easier to see which line is which in the `\showoutput` log. Also added a picture mode making a line every 12pt to show the intended baseline spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,xcolor}
\def\fqdi{fqd}
\def\fqdv{\fqdi\ \fqdi\ \fqdi\ \fqdi\ \fqdi\ }
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
\itshape 

0\begin{picture}(0,0)
\multiput(9,0)(0,-12){10}{\line(-1,0){15}}
\end{picture}

1\fqdv\fqdv

\vskip-\prevdepth\vskip\dp\strutbox

\begin{longtable}{cc}
\color{red}2\fqdv\fqdv&\color{red}\fqdv\fqdv\\
\end{longtable}

\vskip-\dp\strutbox
3\fqdv\fqdv

\vskip-\prevdepth\vskip\dp\strutbox

\begin{longtable}{cc}
\color{red}4\fqdv\fqdv&\color{red}\fqdv\fqdv
\end{longtable}

5\fqdv\fqdv

\fqdv\fqdv

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\color{blue}\fqdv\fqdv&\color{blue}\fqdv\fqdv
\end{tabular}

\fqdv\fqdv
\end{document}
```